# Convert Bitmap image to String format to send over network(LAN) and vice-versa

Tags: c#, .net-remoting, remoteobject

I am basically developing a software in Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4.0 where in I capture the screenshot from a pc and send it over a network to another.
Since I cannot directly send a Bitmap, I have to convert it to String.
I did a lot of internet search but cant find any solution. :(

I found this code on stackoverflow itself.
But it it doesnt work. I tried to print the string (converted from image) but the program behaves like that line doesnt exist.
I used a MessageBox.Show(String);
But not even a msg box pops up!
Can anyone please help? I'm stuck!
Thankx in advance :) (Y)

```
bitmapString = null;       // Conversion from image to string
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
bmpScreenshot.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] bitmapBytes = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
bitmapString = Convert.ToBase64String(bitmapBytes,Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks); // Conversion from image to string end

Image img = null;                           //Conversion from string to image
byte[] bitmapBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(rob);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bitmapBytes);
img = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);   //Conversion from string to image end
```

Comment: Why must it be a string and not just a byte buffer?

Comment: You could send it over using a text based encoding, but why not send the image as a binary stream?

Comment: Anywhere in your implementation of this code are you giving it a path to the image you want converted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to convert it to a byte array:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image img)
{
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Close();

        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

I believe you can simply cast a Bitmap object to an Image object.  So `Image img = (Image)myBitmap;` - then pass that into the method above.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to be a string? What method are you using to send it over the network? A webservice? Direct sockets?

Regardless of how you're sending it though, the best way would be to convert it to a byte array and then pass that array over the network

If you need some code of how to do this, check out similar questions on SO, like [Sending and receiving an image over sockets with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749964/sending-and-receiving-an-image-over-sockets-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly send the individual bytes, but if you really want a string you can encode it in a format called [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Here's the msdn documentation for [encoding to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and [decoding from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) this format. You can convert the image to a byte array using the code @AdamPlocher posted in his answer (which I +1'ed as he saved me from doing it ;) )