# Is there a way to pipe an image directly to a suave response stream?

Tags: f#, suave

I want to dynamically generate an image on server side and send it to the browser.

Currently I'm using a `MemoryStream` to convert it to `byte array` and then usual suave api. See bellow:

```
let draw (text:string) =

  let redBr = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)
  let whiteBr = new SolidBrush(Color.White)
  let i = new Bitmap(600,400)
  let g = Graphics.FromImage i
  let f = new Font("Courier", float32 <| 24.0)
  g.FillRectangle(whiteBr, float32 <| 0.0, float32 <| 0.0, float32 <| 600.0, float32 <| 400.0 )
  g.DrawString(text, f, redBr, float32 <| 10.0, float32 <| 40.0)
  g.Flush()
  let ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()
  i.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png)
  ms.ToArray()

let app : WebPart =
  Writers.setMimeType "image/png"
  >=> (Successful.ok <| draw "bibi")
```

I feel that the `MemoryStream` part can be avoided if suave is allowing us to pipe directly to the response stream.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You basically do this:

```
open System.IO
open Suave
open Suave.Sockets
open Suave.Sockets.Control

path "/byte-stream" >=> (fun ctx ->

  let write (conn, _) = socket {
    use ms = new MemoryStream()
    ms.Write([| 1uy; 2uy; 3uy |], 0, 3)
    ms.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore
    // do things here
    let! (_,conn) = asyncWriteLn (sprintf "Content-Length: %d\r\n" ms.Length) conn
    let! conn = flush conn
    do! transferStream conn ms
    return conn
  }

  { ctx with
      response =
        { ctx.response with
            status = HTTP_200.status
            content = SocketTask write } }
  |> succeed
)
```

Comment: Hi @henrik, the `MemoryStream` I wanted to avoid.Basically my aproach is working. What is doing is after generating the image `Save` it on a `MemoryStream` which then is converted to array and then sent as response. My feeling was that somehow it can be sent directly as response.

Comment: You can either hand Suave a stream, like I showed you above, or you can write bytes to the socket yourself using the sibling functions to `transferStream`. It depends on your implementation of Save.

Comment: It is not my implementation of `Save` it is the `System.Drawing.Image` class method. The `.net` api. I don't know how to get access to it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are concerned about allocating an unnecessary object. I think such concern is commendable.

What you are probably after is an Bitmap API where the bytes of the PNG image is provided through `Stream<byte>` and the Bitmap API then produces when needed by the socket.

`System.Drawing` doesn't seem to support such behavior, possibly [`WIC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff973956.aspx) does (.NET wrappers exists through the excellent [`SharpDX`](http://sharpdx.org/) library).

However, this would mean keeping potentially expensive objects (bitmap, brushes and so on) alive for the duration of the transfer. The byte array might be a more efficient way to store the result.

Another approach in order to avoid allocating objects unnecessarily is caching them. It's made a bit more problematic because `System.Drawing` objects are mutable and not safe to use from multiple threads. You can however create a cache per thread using `ThreadLocal`.

In the sample code below most objects are cached per `Thread`. The only object created per call to `draw` is the byte array returned but that is probably an efficient storage of the PNG data (it's possible the calls `System.Drawing` allocates objects but we have no control over that). As I didn't figure out a way to listen for the "death" of a Thread it means it's important to manually dispose the objects using the `dispose` method when the Thread no longer needs the objects.

Hope this was interesting

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Drawing.Imaging
open System.IO
open System.Threading

module BitmapCreator =
  module internal Details =
    let dispose (d : IDisposable) =
      if d <> null then
        try
          d.Dispose ()
        with
        | e -> () // TODO: log

    // state is ThreadLocal, it means the resources gets initialized once per thread
    let state =
      let initializer () =
        // Allocate all objects needed for work
        let font        = new Font("Courier", 24.0F)
        let red         = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)
        let white       = new SolidBrush(Color.White)
        let bitmap      = new Bitmap(600,400)
        let g           = Graphics.FromImage bitmap
        let ms          = new MemoryStream 1024
        // disposer should be called when Thread is terminating to reclaim
        //  resources as fast as possible
        let disposer () =
          dispose ms
          dispose g
          dispose bitmap
          dispose white
          dispose red
          dispose font
        font, red, white, bitmap, g, ms, disposer

      new ThreadLocal<_>(initializer)

  // Draws text on a bitmap and returns that as a byte array
  let draw text =
    // Grab the state for the current thread
    let font, red, white, bitmap, g, ms, _ = Details.state.Value

    g.FillRectangle(white, 0.0F, 0.0F, 600.0F, 400.0F)
    g.DrawString(text, font, red, 10.0F, 40.0F)
    g.Flush()

    // Resets the memory stream
    //  The capacity is preserved meaning as long as the generated
    //  images is equal or smaller in size no realloc is needed
    ms.Seek (0L, SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore
    ms.SetLength 0L

    bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png)

    // Here a new array is allocated per call
    //  Depending on how FillRectangle/DrawString works this is hopefully our
    //  only allocation
    ms.ToArray()

  // Disposes all BitmapCreator resources held by the current thread
  let dispose () =
    let _, _, _, _, _, _, disposer = Details.state.Value
    disposer ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  // Saves some bitmaps to file, the name include the thread pid in order
  //  to not overwrite other threads' images
  let save () =
    let texts = [|"Hello"; "There"|]
    let tid   = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
    for text in texts do
      File.WriteAllBytes (sprintf "%s_%d.png" text tid, BitmapCreator.draw text)

  // Runs a in other thread, disposes BitmapCreator resources when done
  let runInOtherThread (a : unit -> unit) =
    let a () =
      try
        a ()
      finally
        BitmapCreator.dispose ()
    let thread = Thread a
    thread.Start ()
    thread.Join ()

  Environment.CurrentDirectory <- AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

  try
    save () // Here we allocate BitmapCreator resources
    save () // Since the same thread is calling the resources will reused
    runInOtherThread save // New thread, new resources
    runInOtherThread save // New thread, new resources
  finally
    BitmapCreator.dispose ()

  0
```

Answer (score 0):

This question relates more generally to saving an image directly to a socket in .NET, not really specific to F# or Suave.  There is some discussion at this link which I think basically concludes you will be stuck with the creation of a temp buffer first, whether through MemoryStream or calling .ToArray() on the image.  [Sending and receiving an image over sockets with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749964/sending-and-receiving-an-image-over-sockets-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi everyone, to make it clearer, what bothered me in my original question was the need to use an additional object just to get access to Bitmap underlying data. So, while already having the image in memory, I needed to create a transition object, the `MemoryStream` just to make a copy of the data as an array which then to be handed to Suave to deliver it to the browser.

I hoped to find something simmilar to nodejs pipes: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_pipe