# my send function(socket librarys:system.net & system.net.sockets) has some errors

Tags: c#, sockets

I´m programming a client/server application in c#

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///openfile
            OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = file.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Socket send = new Socket(addressFamily.internetwork,                                    
            socketType.stream, protocolType.tcp);
            Socket send = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,                                    
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint port = new 
            IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip.Text),int.Parse(Port.Text));
            send.Send(port);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   }

        private void label3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   }
    }
}
```

and my error is :

> Error    2   The best overloaded method match System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(System.Collections.Generic.IList>)'
>   has some invalid arguments    C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs    53  13  WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> and  Error    3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.IPEndPoint'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList>' C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs    53  23  WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: please read the [documentation of the Send method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.send?view=netframework-4.8) none of its variations take an `IPEndPoint` as argument

Comment: what is the data that you want to send?

Comment: picture or every files

Answer (score 0):

The `IpEndPoint` does not belong into the [Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.send?view=netframework-4.8) method. This method wants data to be transmitted. The [EndPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.endpoint?view=netframework-4.8) belongs into the [Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connect?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Connect_System_Net_EndPoint_) method.

Hence your error message.

You surely want to connect first, before trying to send data:

```
send.Connect(port);
```

> picture or every files

If you want to send pictures via socket you should have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749964/sending-and-receiving-an-image-over-sockets-with-c-sharp)

Comment: @Compo_corp did you change this line: `send.Send(port);` ? if not, then of course there is no change...

Comment: how change that?vhange what?

Comment: @Compo_corp did you look at the link that I posted? you need a little more work. Basically load the file, get all bytes and then send the byte array